# Inconsistent player tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I am seeing player tags with either just the last name or the first name and the last name.  I think we should stick to a consistent format. I would suggest that [firstname-lastname](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firstname-lastname) is a good format, for example, [bobby-fischer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bobby-fischer) or [gary-kasparov](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gary-kasparov).  Also, since most people know Bobby Fischer as Bobby Fischer and not Robert James Fischer, I don't think it is necessary to make it [robert-james-fischer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robert-james-fischer)?

Status: not completed.

Comment: I'm bumping this because *bobby-fischer* and *boris-spassky* has resurfaced. Moderators should take action to keep tags consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm merging [mikhail-tal](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mikhail-tal) into [tal](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tal), [boris-gelfand](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boris-gelfand) into [gelfand](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gelfand), and [vasily-smyslov](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vasily-smyslov) into [smyslov](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smyslov), but leaving [donald-byrne](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-byrne) as is, because of possible future confusion with Robert Byrne.

The rest of the tags seem consistent with the last-name-except-for-ambiguous-cases rule, so the above are all that I see need to be changed.  Comment here if I missed something.

Comment: Great, I might change my last name to Tal, so you might have to reconsider that one j/k :)

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest sticking to a single last name except in cases where the first is needed for clarification. If necessary, we could create aliases later to tie them back together. I think it would save on space and clarity, but still provide a means of specificity if necessary.

Also, it's helpful to note that there are currently only tags existing for the first of the following. That suggests it's the more natural for folks in this case.

[fischer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fischer) [bobby-fischer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bobby-fischer) [robert-james-fischer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robert-james-fischer) [fischer-robert](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fischer-robert)

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be cases where an opening and a player would share the same tag, for example [tag:alekhine] and [tag:alekhines-defense].  Or [tag:petrosian] (variation in KID).  I don't think it's an issue (fill out the tag wiki's well), but just something to be aware of.

Comment: OK, I think just the last name would suffice unless we have situations like the ones Andrew pointed out or if their is two  or more players share the same last name such as the Polgar sisters.

Comment: And Emanuel vs. Edward Lasker, and Donald vs. Robert Byrne...